# How to change a field value in a data-frame when you know the column and a row reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a large data-frame called `df` which looks like:

```
       First Name  Last name        Dept  Location Status       Concat 
    0          Jo      Jones    Accounts   Bristol Current     JonesJo
    1         Sid      Smith       Sales      Hull New        SmithSid
    2        Phil      Evans  Production      Hull Current   EvansPhil
    3       Sarah      Heath   Marketing   Bristol Current  HeathSarah
    4        Jane       Hill    Accounts   Bristol Current    HillJane
    5         Amy     Cooper       Sales      Hull Current   CooperAmy

23453      Marcus      Price  Operations      Hull Current PriceMarcus
23454      Andrew       King      Design   Bristol Current  KingAndrew
23455        Emma       Lane   Marketing   Bristol Current    LaneEmma
23456       Brian       Deen    Accounts   Bristol Current   DeenBrian       
23457       Steve      Jacks      Design   Bristol Current  JacksSteve
```

Is there a way to change a field value in a record if you know the 'co-ordinates' of the field to change.

For example I'm trying to change Amy Cooper's 'Dept' value from 'Sales' to 'Accounts' could I do something like:

```
value = 'Accounts'
ConcatName = 'CooperAmy'
columnName = 'Dept'

df.ix[df['Concat']= ConcatName ,columnName ] = value
```

nb. All Concat values will be unique

So my resulting data-frame would look like:

```
       First Name  Last name        Dept  Location Status       Concat 
    0          Jo      Jones    Accounts   Bristol Current     JonesJo
    1         Sid      Smith       Sales      Hull New        SmithSid
    2        Phil      Evans  Production      Hull Current   EvansPhil
    3       Sarah      Heath   Marketing   Bristol Current  HeathSarah
    4        Jane       Hill    Accounts   Bristol Current    HillJane
    5         Amy     Cooper    Accounts      Hull Current   CooperAmy

23453      Marcus      Price  Operations      Hull Current PriceMarcus
23454      Andrew       King      Design   Bristol Current  KingAndrew
23455        Emma       Lane   Marketing   Bristol Current    LaneEmma
23456       Brian       Deen    Accounts   Bristol Current   DeenBrian       
23457       Steve      Jacks      Design   Bristol Current  JacksSteve
```

Comment: that would work except you need `==`: `df.ix[df['Concat']== ConcatName ,columnName ] = value`, also you should `loc` as `ix` is deprecated `df.loc[df['Concat'] == ConcatName ,columnName ] = value`

Comment: May using .at for better performance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming combinations of `'First Name'` and `'Last name'` are unique in your dataframe, you can use a `MultiIndex` and then set a scalar via [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['First Name', 'Last name'])
df.at[('Amy', 'Cooper'), 'Dept'] = 'Accounts'
```

After changing your index, you can no longer access your series via `df['First Name']`. For this, use `df.index.get_level_values('First Name')`. If you need the index as columns again at a subsequent stage, you can use `df = df.reset_index()`.

[`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is a more complex indexing tool and preferable when you have multiple values to set / replace.